# Windows 8.1 Weather live tile occassionally displays weather for Washington, DC and not my home city until the app is restarted

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, live-tiles, weather

For some reason, the Weather live tile on the Start screen sometimes displays the weather for Washington, DC instead of the correct New York, despite having set the home location:

[image: Weather live tile always displays weather for Washington, DC]

This issue persists until I fully close and restart the Weather app. If I don't open the Weather app for some time, the tile reverts to Washington, DC. How do I make sure it always displays the weather for my home city?

Comment: OK I'm not a Win 8 person so this may be wrong.  When you right click on the tile, does it show a menu? If it does look for options.  There should/may be an option to select you home city. HTH

Comment: Do you use a VPN or some other kind of dynamic access to the internet?

Comment: @Keltari, no. I'm just using a regular Internet connection through Wi-Fi.